# Nuxt auth logout redirect

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a problem with nuxt auth module while loging out:

In my templates I used directly user.avatar lets say for images on 10 places.

Now when I use `this.$auth.logout()` it does the job but before redirecting with middleware or by using `this.$router.replace('/')` I get a lot of errors that avatar is undefined.

One way is to check for each is avatar undefined or not. But it takes a lot of changing.

Is there a way to redirect just after changing state?

Comment: You'd need a `v-if="loggedIn"` on the img tag.

Comment: Well thats the same as checking is avatar undefined. Is there a way to redirect like before changing the state. I mean I could not use auth module but since it is there. I cannot be that no one had this problem before.

Comment: @Learner - how did you solve this?

Comment: @zerohedge I made my custom auth module